# Feed multiple parameters from node to mssql using node-mssql and stored procedures

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, stored-procedures

I have already got simple SQL calls working in my Node API backend. I am using stored procedures with node-mssql. The simple code that is working looks like this:

```
//pull in the connection string
sql.connect(connection).then(pool => {
    // Stored procedure    
    return pool.request()
        .input('email', sql.VarChar(120), extraColon)
        .execute('Login');
}).then(result => {
    res.send(result);
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
```

This works every time with no issues on several different calls. I am starting to need to pass muliple parameters with my latest calls and thought this would also be easy like this:

```
//pull in the connection string
sql.connect(connection).then(pool => {
    // Stored procedure    
    return pool.request()
        .input(('email', sql.VarChar(120), extraColon),
        ('password', sql.VarChar(120), extraColon1))
        .execute('Login');
}).then(result => {
    res.send(result);
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
```

I added 2 But it doesn't recognize what I am passing. I am not looking for anything that is drastically different than this, just the simple way to pass multiple parameters into my stored procedure. I am passing a payload from React to my Node JS back end, splitting it into the pieces I need, then passing them as individual parameters. Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you just add another line beginning with .input for each parameter like this:

```
sql.connect(connection).then(pool => {
    // Stored procedure    
    return pool.request()
        .input('email', sql.VarChar(120), extraColon)
        .input('password', sql.VarChar(120), extraColon1)
        .execute('Login');
}).then(result => {
    res.send(result);
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
```

This works for me with more parameters as well.