# Send table type as param to procedure from nodejs msnodesqlv8

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I create a procedure that one of the parameters (`mediaValue` param) is a table type.

I use msnodesqlv8 package in nodejs to connect to SQL Server. But I have a problem sending table type to the procedure.

This is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addCustomer] 
    @customerType nvarchar(50),
    @customerCad bigint,
    @phoneNumbers char(100),
    @email varchar(500),
    @fname nvarchar(200),
    @lname nvarchar(200),
    @representative bigint,
    @link bigint,
    @birthday varchar(50),
    @occupation nvarchar(300),
    @financialLevel nvarchar(200),
    @gender nvarchar(50),
    @city bigint,
    @fullAdress nvarchar(1000),
    @mediaValue mediaType READONLY,
    @operatorId bigint
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customers (cType, cgId, emailAddress, fname, lname, representative, linkType, birthday, occupation, financialLevel, gender, cityId, fullAddress, operatorId)
    VALUES (@customerType, @customerCad, @email, @fname, @lname, @representative, @link, @birthday, @occupation, @financialLevel, @gender, @city, @fullAdress, @operatorId);


    DECLARE @cId bigint;
    SET @cId = IDENT_CURRENT('customers');

    INSERT INTO phoneBank (cId, phoneNumber)
        SELECT @cId, value 
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@phoneNumbers,',');

    INSERT INTO customerMediaValue (cId, mediaId, mediaTitle) 
        SELECT @cId, mediaId, mediaTitle 
        FROM @mediaValue;

    SELECT @cId AS customerId;
END
```

My table type (`mediaType`) is defined like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[mediaType] AS TABLE
(
    [cId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [mediaId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [mediaTitle] [nvarchar](300) NULL
)
GO
```

I call the procedure from nodejs like this:

```
const generateTable = () => {
  const table = {
    columns: [
      { name: "cId", type: "bigint" },
      { name: "mediaId", type: "bigint" },
      { name: "mediaTitle", type: "nvarchar(300)" },
    ],
    rows: [[29, 1, "test"]],
  };
  return table;
};

const addNewCustomer = async (con, req, resp) => {
  const {
    customerType,
    customerCad,
    phoneNumbers,
    email,
    fname,
    family,
    representative,
    link,
    birthday,
    occupation,
    financialLevel,
    gender,
    city,
    fullAddress,
    mediaValue,
    operatorId,
  } = req.body;

  try {
    const table = generateTable();
    const result = con.promises.query(
      `exec addCustomer @customerType = N'${customerType}',@customerCad = ${customerCad},@phoneNumbers='${phoneNumbers}',@email='${email}',@fname=N'${fname}',@lname=N'${family}',@representative=${representative},@link=${link},@birthday='${birthday}',@occupation=N'${occupation}',@financialLevel=N'${financialLevel}',@gender=N'${gender}',@city=${city},@fullAdress=N'${fullAddress}',@mediaValue=${table},@operatorId=${operatorId}`
    );
    result
      .then((result) => {
        resp.status(200).send(result.results[0]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        resp.status(500).send(circular.stringify(err));
      });
  } catch (err) {
    return resp
      .status(500)
      .send({ msg: serverError, err: circular.stringify(err) });
  }
```

but I got this error

```
"sqlstate":"22018"
```

I also found some help from mssnodeqlv8 GitHub
[github link](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/issues/254)

but I couldn't solve this.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `IDENT_CURRENT()` to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: I would recommend starting your stored proc off with `SET NOCOUNT ON`. You've got three insert statements executing before the final select statement and their rowcount output could confuse Node.

Comment: That's really not how you are supposed to pass parameters. Do **not** inject data into your SQL, pass them as proper parameters, in this case using `.input` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164863/feed-multiple-parameters-from-node-to-mssql-using-node-mssql-and-stored-procedur Once you have done that you can just pass `table` as a parameter value

Comment: @Charlieface . yeah I switch to mssql and I did table as param.